web3.exceptions.ContractLogicError: execution reverted: STF (I approved)
    amount_in_max,path,uniswap_contract_address,uniswap_router_abi=self.preview_swap(uniswap_router,token1,token2,amountin)
    deadline = int(time.time()) + (60 * 20)

    w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(self.infura_url))

    contract = w3.eth.contract(address=uniswap_contract_address, abi=uniswap_router_abi)
    print(amountin)
    payload=(path[0],path[1],10000,self.account_address,int(amountin*10**6),0,0)

    tx_to_send = contract.functions.exactInputSingle(payload).build_transaction()

I have the web3.exceptions.ContractLogicError: execution reverted: STF error, the only solution that i found online is related to approving the tokens but i have approven them, parth[0] is the token address that i want to trade to get the path[1] token address
I'm in polygon
